# LibGDX-How to access child actor's attributes through group

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I have a Group and some Actors in it. In the actor, i have an attribute called colorCode. Now when I use

```
myGroup.getChildren().get(index)
```

I get a list of methods from Actor class which does not include my getters/setters.
Any idea how to access my attributes inside the actor ?

Comment: You sure they are public? Have you tried a single object instead of a group and does that work? Do you need to cast to the proper child class, in case you have multiple different childs of the parent class in the group?

Comment: @MennoGouw I am able to get after type-casting. THanks :)